# Weblogic. Add one more domain with SOA

Tags: weblogic, soa, weblogic-10.x

I have got task, to add one more domain with SOA app to Weblogic server. As I understand, I have to run RCU and create schemas for new domain before running ./config.sh

The problem is that I not sure is this correct solution. There is a lot step by step manuals how to create domain, but is there any differences when adding second domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add domain to WebLogic server. Domain is like logical grouping of related WebLogic servers. You can either extend existing domain to include SOA application or create whole new domain with SOA application. In both cases you will need to run RCU at some point before initially lunching your domain. It's best that you read/follow oracle documentation related to your specific version of WebLogic/Oracle Fusion Middleware.

Comment: Possibly I wasn't clear enough. I wanted to have two domains with SOA on one server. As you wrote

Answer (score 0):

To add second domain, at first you have to run RCU: 
`cd RCU_HOME/bin
./rcu`
 and create new repository. When repository is created, you need to run config.sh:
`cd SOA_ORACLE_HOME/common/bin
./config.sh` to create new domain.

Be careful when creating soa_server: ports numbers used for soa and admin server shouldn't be the same, as in first domain, and soa_server name should be different.

More info about creating domain you can find here: 
https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/weblogic-11g-create-extend-and-remove-domains
and here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/install.1111/e14318/qisoa.htm#CACCAEBE